# Do I need SharePoint 2013 Enterprise to use MySites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, mysite, mysites, active-directory-import, adi

Having some issues trying to get an answer on this question: Do I need the SharePoint 2013 Enterprise license, if I'm going to use MySites.

I recall from a previous setup, that when you set up the AD Sync (ADI), you have the option to then configure MySites, and the site collection for that falls below the Enterprise template tab.

But I'm not sure if I actually really need to set up that feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't. It is part of the Standard license.

It falls below the "Enterprise" tag in "Create new site collection", but it is not part of the Enterprise license.

See for example under "Social features" here: https://florianlaumer.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-standard-vs-enterprise-vs-foundation-feature-comparison-matrix/

Comment: Thanks Robert, appreciate the answer. I think that's where the confusion cropped up.